# PHP SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Cómo están?

EStoy haciendo una conexión a un servidor Webservice. Por medio de PHP

Para realizar una prueba utilice SOAP-UI y el servicio responde correctamente, pero al momento de realizar la conexión con PHP me arroja el error

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://urlwebservice' : failed to load external entity "http://urlwebservice"

Ya probé mandando el contexto en el PHP

```
    $opts = array('http'=>array('user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = new SoapClient('http://urlwebservice',array('stream_context' => $context,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

    $result = $client->WS_cotiza($xml);
    print_r($result);
```

He buscado varios códigos PHP para conectarme pero nada, y sigue funcionando en SOAP-IU y el url del webservices si es accesible desde navegador

Espero sus comentarios y ojala nos puedan ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que las dos URLs son iguales? Yo he tenido problemas similares porque un WSDL usaba un tipo definido en otro WSDL, y el segundo WSDL no estaba accesible.

Comment: Sí, se supone que estoy accedediendo al recurso correcto. y ni siquiera tien algun endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

El URL está mal; debes poder ver el WSDL si abres ese URL en un browser y `http://urlwebservice` no existe. También crear un cliente SOAP de una manera más sencilla usando el WSDL, lo siguiente nombra las funciones configuradas en un WSDL público para efectos de prueba:

```
$ws = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl', ['trace' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'user_agent' => 'Mi cliente SOAP']);
var_dump($ws->__getFunctions());
```

Solamente reemplaza la URL con la de tu WSDL y estarás bien.